# Oracle joining tables with null columns

Tags: sql, oracle, join, select

I want to join 4 tables, like in a code below. Where IIN is primary key. But if IIN doenst exist in one table, my code's result will be null.

```
SELECT 
  COALESCE(D.TERRORIST, 0) as TERRORIST,
  COALESCE(D.SPECIAL,0) as SPECIAL,
  COALESCE(T.SIGN_INACTIVE, 0) as TAXPAYER,
  COALESCE(B.ANOTHER, 0) as OSB,
  COALESCE(B.LSBOO,0) as LSBOO,
  COALESCE(R.DELAY,0) as DELAY
FROM RBPM.LIST_CL_DWHFM D
    JOIN RBPM.LIST_CL_TAXPAYER T
      ON D.IIN = T.IIN
    JOIN RBPM.LIST_CL_BLACK B
      ON T.IIN = B.IIN
    JOIN RBPM.LIST_CL_RBO R
      ON B.IIN = R.IIN
WHERE 1=1
AND D.IIN = '123456789123'
```

For example:

Table RBPM.LIST_CL_DWHFM

| IIN | TERRORIST | SPECIAL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| null | null | null |

Table RBPM.LIST_CL_TAXPAYER

| IIN | TAXPAYER |
| --- | --- |
| '123456789123' | 0 |

Table RBPM.LIST_CL_BLACK

| IIN | OSB | LSBOO |
| --- | --- | --- |
| '123456789123' | 0 | 1 |

Table RBPM.LIST_CL_RBO

| IIN | DELAY |
| --- | --- |
| '123456789123' | 0 |

Expecting:

| TERRORIST | SPECIAL | TAXPAYER | OSB | LSBOO | DELAY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| null | null | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |

Result:

| TERRORIST | SPECIAL | TAXPAYER | OSB | LSBOO | DELAY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| null | null | null | null | null | null |

Comment: Use LEFT JOIN instead of JOIN

Comment: Your post is not clear. [mre]

Answer (score 0):

If any table might have a null IIN you can build a list of all the IINs and left join onto it, (though it would be better to have at least one table that has all the IINs):

```
SELECT 
 COALESCE(D.TERRORIST, 0) as TERRORIST,
 COALESCE(D.SPECIAL,0) as SPECIAL,
 COALESCE(T.SIGN_INACTIVE, 0) as TAXPAYER,
 COALESCE(B.ANOTHER, 0) as OSB,
 COALESCE(B.LSBOO,0) as LSBOO,
 COALESCE(R.DELAY,0) as DELAY
FROM 
 (
  SELECT IIN FROM RBPM.LIST_CL_DWHFM
  UNION
  SELECT IIN FROM RBPM.LIST_CL_TAXPAYER
  UNION
  SELECT IIN FROM RBPM.LIST_CL_BLACK
  UNION
  SELECT IIN FROM RBPM.LIST_CL_RBO
 ) a
 LEFT JOIN RBPM.LIST_CL_DWHFM D ON a.IIN = D.IIN
 LEFT JOIN RBPM.LIST_CL_TAXPAYER T ON a.IIN = T.IIN
 LEFT JOIN RBPM.LIST_CL_BLACK B ON a.IIN = B.IIN
 LEFT JOIN RBPM.LIST_CL_RBO R ON a.IIN = R.IIN
WHERE 1=1
AND a.IIN = '123456789123'
```

You could also full outer join everything and put a coalesce/multiple or in the where. I left the WHERE 1=1 in on the assumption that you're programmatically concatenating other clauses on; if you arent, remove it

If you're only ever going to query one IIN you can:

```
SELECT 
 COALESCE(D.TERRORIST, 0) as TERRORIST,
 COALESCE(D.SPECIAL,0) as SPECIAL,
 COALESCE(T.SIGN_INACTIVE, 0) as TAXPAYER,
 COALESCE(B.ANOTHER, 0) as OSB,
 COALESCE(B.LSBOO,0) as LSBOO,
 COALESCE(R.DELAY,0) as DELAY
FROM 
 (
  SELECT '123456789123' AS IIN FROM DUAL
 ) x
 LEFT JOIN RBPM.LIST_CL_DWHFM D ON x.IIN = D.IIN
 LEFT JOIN RBPM.LIST_CL_TAXPAYER T ON x.IIN = T.IIN
 LEFT JOIN RBPM.LIST_CL_BLACK B ON x.IIN = B.IIN
 LEFT JOIN RBPM.LIST_CL_RBO R ON x.IIN = R.IIN
```

Comment: Please, when asking for help, never say "I got an error" without giving the full exact error message

Answer (score 0):

NOW IT WORKS WELL WITH NULL COLUMNS,

```
SELECT 
     COALESCE(D.TERRORIST, 0) as TERRORIST,
     COALESCE(D.SPECIAL,0) as SPECIAL,
     COALESCE(T.SIGN_INACTIVE, 0) as TAXPAYER,
     COALESCE(B.ANOTHER, 0) as EX_OSB,
     COALESCE(B.LSBOO,0) as LSBOO,
     COALESCE(R.DELAY,0) as DELAY
    FROM 
     (
      SELECT IIN FROM RBPM.LIST_CL_DWHFM
      WHERE IIN = '123456789123'
      UNION
      SELECT IIN FROM RBPM.LIST_CL_TAXPAYER
      WHERE IIN = '123456789123'
      UNION
      SELECT IIN FROM RBPM.LIST_CL_BLACK
      WHERE IIN = '123456789123'
      UNION
      SELECT IIN FROM RBPM.LIST_CL_RBO
      WHERE IIN = '123456789123'
     ) ALLT
     LEFT JOIN RBPM.LIST_CL_DWHFM D ON ALLT.IIN = D.IIN
     LEFT JOIN RBPM.LIST_CL_TAXPAYER T ON ALLT.IIN = T.IIN
     LEFT JOIN RBPM.LIST_CL_BLACK B ON ALLT.IIN = B.IIN
     LEFT JOIN RBPM.LIST_CL_RBO R ON ALLT.IIN = R.IIN
    WHERE COALESCE(ALLT.IIN, '123456789123') = '123456789123'
```

thanks Caius Jard

Comment: It's nearly pointless to query the tables like that and UNION them; you can just query DUAL like I did in the edit to my answer. The only advantage to querying thus is if the IIN doesn't exist in any table you get no rows. You don't need the WHERE clause at all - the subquery will definitely either return a single value `'123456789123'` or no rows at all; there is nothing to coalesce/the where is always true or moot